# Creating a tree-shaked bundle of Tabulator with Rollup

Tags: javascript, tabulator, bundling-and-minification, rollupjs

I would like to decrease the file size of Tabulator by creating bundles that only use the features I need for specific tables. I followed the advice in the docs for [Core With Optional Modules](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/install#setup-basic), but I always end up with a bundle containing all the optional modules.

First I tried by downloading dist/js/tabulator_esm.js and creating a tabulator_rollup.js file with the contents:

```
import {Tabulator, FormatModule, EditModule} from './tabulator_esm';

Tabulator.registerModule([FormatModule, EditModule]);

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  //table setup options
});
```

Command line invocation used:

```
rollup tabulator_rollup.js --file tabulator_bundle.js --format iife
```

I also tried installing Tabulator from npm and referring to tabulator-tables in my tabulator_rollup.js file, running `rollup -c` against this configuration file:

```
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  input: 'tabulator_rollup.js',
  output: {
    file: 'tabulator_bundle.js',
    format: 'iife',
  },
  plugins: [
    resolve({
      browser: true,
    }),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score -1):

[It turns out Tabulator does not yet support this](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/4070).